# Did Muhammed know about organs inside human beings?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, human-body

My doubt came to when I read about jibreal taken out the heart of Prophet and washed the heart in zam zam water. So I was wondering how did the people in that time know about heart and organs in human being.

Did Muhammed know about organs inside human beings?

Comment: If from nowhere else, then from battlefields. In general, better fit for [history.se] I think.

Comment: Why shouldn't he know about it they used too slaughter animals, the point is whether he knew the functions!

Answer (score 2):

Well, everyone knew about the heart and basic organs, because animals were eaten in those days. There was no great surgery but still there was some medical science.

So, heart being the primary part of the body, even historically and logically we know people knew about heart and mind(at-least their importance, if not how to FIX them).

And if we take this in general, that if prophet knew about each part of body in detail? than I think we can't say, but it is highly unlikely. His role and duty was being a messenger of Allah. Not being a surgeon or a scientist. If Allah would had told him the details of human body and organs, he would have surely told them to us.

> "**I am only a human being. When I command you with something regarding
>   your religion, accept it. When I command you with something from my
>   own opinion, know that I am only a human being. You know worldly
>   affairs better than me."** (Muslim, Fadail, 140-141)

So, we don't say what we don't know. Or what has not reached us.

### Allah knows best

Answer (score -1):

Yes this story is clearly stated in the hadhith when his heart was taken out in order to fill it with wisdom knowledge.regarding the question in think people at that time knew about this